# Creating new Post through the LinkedIn Groups API with JS?

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

Is there any example how to use the groups LinkedIn API with JS?

I want to

- retrieve group posts
- create new group posts

There are no examples in the [Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api), but it was mentention in the forum that the groups API can also be accessed with JS.

Best

M

-- update: this was working for me

```
IN.API.Raw("groups/{id}/posts")
.method("POST")
.body(JSON.stringify({ "title": "hi title", "summary": "hi summary" }))
.result(function success(res) {
    console.log(res);
})
.error(function error(e) {
    console.log(e);
});

IN.API.Raw("groups/{id}/posts")
.method("GET")
.result(function success(results) {
    console.log(results);
})
.error(function error(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inapiraw

You can make calls for items where there isn't a js helper created by using the .raw helper.